# Pre - Flared copper pipes for HVAC Unit? Advantages / Disadvantages?

Tags: hvac

I bought several HVAC to be installed as heating / cooling in a house I own. The most difficult part seems to be the flaring connection of the copper pipe tubing. Now I discovered that you can buy "pre-flared" copper piping. Does anyone have experience using these? (For example available here: (https://www.saturnsales.co.uk/Flared-Copper-Pipes-1/4-1/2.html).

Advantages:
-No need to buy tools
-Save time
-The most difficult installation part can be ommited
-If retailer can be trusted - high quality

Disadvantages
-Higher price?
-Bad quality?

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to flare my own copper tubing (not pipe). By making my own flares I do not have to allow for a line that may be longer than what is actually needed. My preferred flare block is a Ridgid ratcheting flare block that I bought in about 1970 and still makes perfect flares.

Comment: Which flaring tool (company?) would you recommend. I've seen huge price differences

Comment: @Rubus The one he put in the post... I have one from them as well, a bit newer by about 15 years...